# add UIView and pan it, then remove it when touch is released

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to create a button when user tap a button or hold it.
My expectations are that when the button is held down, the new UIView is created, it become the first responder to the pan gesture, and when the user's touch is released, the UIView is removed from it super view.
Also, I the view to be centred on where the user tapping on the button.

Now, I have completed the panning and adding the view and removing it. But I have 2 issues:

- The location of the view is not synced with where the user tapped on the button.
- The new UIView created doesn't become the first responder, means that I need release the button and touch the UIView to pan it. I need it to become the first responder, where when it just appears, I can pan it around.

Here is my code:

```
private let myButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addView), for: UIControlEvents.touchDown)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return button
}()

private let myCircularUIView: UIView = {
    let imageView = UIView()
    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
}()

@objc private func addView() {
    view.addSubview(myCircularUIView)
    view.becomeFirstResponder()
    myCircularUIView.frame = CGRect(origin: translation, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
    let gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGesture(recognizer:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
}

private var translation = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

@objc private func panGesture(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
    myCircularUIView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: translation.x, y: translation.y)
}
```

Please, if you need any extra info, let me know instead of downvoting.